# How do I render JS in Rails 1.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, legacy-code

I have the following code as a controller action:

```
def create
  render :js => "alert('hello')"
end
```

But when I go to this view, I get a missing template error – 'create.rhtml'. What is the correct way to render a javascript response in Rails 1.2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render :file is probably your best bet with Rails that old. You can also use the old RJS style.

Comment: respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :text => "alert('hello')" }
    end